# Как правильно составить SQL запрос с вставкой значения из переменной?

Tags: php, sql

Есть вот такой запрос:

```
$sql_ticket = "SELECT * FROM tickets 
               WHERE `id`=".$id." AND `status`=\"close\" ORDER BY id DESC";
```

Если вместо `".$id."` вставить нужное число, то запрос выполняется. Если нужное число я передаю через переменную, то выдает ошибку:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'AND `status`="close" ORDER BY id DESC' at line 1

Что не так делаю? Помогите пожалуйста разобраться. Уже всё что знаю перепробовал, не пойму что не так то...

Comment: может у вас в айдишнике нет числа? Можете полный код написать, что до запроса?

Comment: Покажите, какая строка у вас получается в переменной $sql_tikket в процессе выполнения коды. Наверняка просто что-то не так подставляется, но чтобы понять, что именно, нужно посмотреть, какая строка получилась после подстановки.

Comment: И п.с ".$id."?? а sql иньекции...

Comment: @ДенисКотляров, ага, 10 штук! Откуда берется `$id` еще не известно, чтобы об инъекции писать.

Comment: Чего 10 штук? А так да тут по сути у автора бардак с php.

Comment: Благодарю за замечание) так и было, присвоение значения переменной было внутри условия, которое выполнялось только при пост запросе, а я гетом переходил.  Извиняюсь не углядел) Бывает...  А на счет инъекций у меня вроде как нормально:   function clearInt($data){
 return abs((int)$data);
}
$id = clearInt($row['id']);

Comment: @КиноТрейлеры это не защита.....это утешение себя, что защита есть))... и что будет если число отрицательное? функция вернет положительное. атата

Comment: @КиноТрейлеры, если вы `$id` получаете из своей же базы, из числового столбца, то ни каких преобразований с ним делать не нужно :) Это избыточные действия.

Comment: в данном конкретном случае это выборка из базы и даже её я подвергаю проверке. А если и гетом будет передано то там может быть только число и только положительное. Зачем мне отрицательное в обычной передаче параметров :)

Comment: @КиноТрейлеры ну вы что на айдишники используете `clearInt`, а на другие числа, которые будут передаваться и могут быть отрицательными `clearInt2`, `clearInt3` и пр? Это же ж бред... а если одну на всё - то тут вы и попадетесь, когда отрицательное должно быть а вы её конвертите

Comment: @Алексей Шиманский , я везде функцию использую чтобы не забыть) как говориться - проверок много не бывает. У меня именно в данном случае нет необходимости принимать числа кроме положительных.

Comment: В общем всех БЛАГОДАРЮ. Я сегодня в первый раз воспользовался данным сервисом и приятно удивлен быстрыми и грамотными ответами, буду и дальше задавать Вам вопросы. Всем пока!

Answer (score 2):

Для того чтобы подобных ошибок **никогда** не возникало, а так же по множеству других причин, чтобы правильно составить SQL запрос с вставкой значения из переменной, эту вставку необходимо производить через **плейсхолдер**.

Это совсем несложно. На примере с использованием [ПДО](http://phpfaq.ru/pdo):

```
# 1. В запросе вместо переменной пишем знак вопроса
$sql = "SELECT * FROM tickets WHERE id=? AND status='close'";

# 2. Затем запрос подготавливаем
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);

# 3. Исполняем запрос, передавая в него переменную.
$stmt->execute([$id]);

# 4. Получаем запрошенные данные.
$ticket = $stmt->fetch()
```

Это очень просто, абсолютно безопасно (в отличие от передачи переменной напрямую в запрос!) и на 100% гарантирует от появления ошибок синтаксиса, вызванных данными.

Любые другие варианты заведомо неверные